# Error Running Powershell Script Using PSCX

Tags: powershell, teamcity, pscx

We're running a Team City build server which already executes this script locally with no problem. However, when I try to run this script manually I have the following problem:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PowerShell Community Extensions Imported.
PS C:\Users\user.domain> cd D:\pkg\platform-2b0c7e3f71f9-BUILD01; powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file D:\pkg\platform-2b0c7e3f71f9-BUILD01\stage.ps1 production \\192.168.x.x\staging \\testserver.domain.com\staging
D:\pkg\platform-2b0c7e3f71f9-BUILD01
Start Staging: 12/15/2014 11:18:14
Verifying target environment configuration and staging targets
Copying source and environment switch
...
Verifying configuration files are valid XML files
Test-Xml : The 'Test-Xml' command was found in the module 'Pscx', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Pscx'.
At D:\pkg\platform-2b0c7e3f71f9-BUILD01\stage.ps1:72 char:9
+   if (!(Test-Xml $file))
+         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-Xml:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

So I see the PowerShell Community Extenstions are getting imported (line 4) which makes me wonder what is going on. I am running the script as the exact same user that runs it under Team City. I've checked the build step I'm trying to replicate:

[image: screen capture of Team City Build step]

and I can't think of anything that I've missed (working directory option is set to the script file's directory). Any ideas would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 4 loads Pscx, Line 5 opens up a new powershell session with -NoProfile option, so it's unlikely that Pscx is loaded in that Powershell session.